# Submit a FORM after it was removed from DOM Tree

Tags: javascript, html, forms, internet-explorer

what i want to do is: i want to keep the form object somewhere and send it later to the server. It works fine if the form just contains text/radio/checkboxes etc. but it doesnt work in Internet Explorer when there is a field for fileupload.

Here an example:

```
<div id="container">
  <form id="testForm">
    <input type="file" name="photo"/> 
  </form>
  <input type="button" onclick="uploadLater();"/>
</div>

function uploadLater()
{
   window.oldForm = document.getElementById('testForm');
   document.getElementById('container').innerHTML = "thanks!";
}
```

another function that is executed later looks like this (note: works in FF and Chrome but NOT in IE, IE sadly doens't send the file):

```
function doItNow()
{
  if(!window.oldForm.parentNode) document.body.append(window.oldForm);
  // ... other parameters omitted ...
  window.oldForm.submit();
  window.oldForm.parentNode.removeChild(window.oldForm);

  alert('hurray! data on its way ...');
}
```

Does anyone know a solution to make something like this work in IE?
Sending a form that contains also a file and is not part of the DOM tree after a certain delay (cross browser).

Thx,

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work?  You would just hide the form, keeping it where it is but not displaying.  Then display another div with your text.

Here is the working copy: http://jsfiddle.net/KhJAt/

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="displayMessage" style="display:none;"></div>
  <form id="testForm">
    <input type="file" name="photo"/> 
  </form>
  <input type="button" onclick="uploadLater();" value="Click it"/>
</div>

function uploadLater()
{
   window.oldForm = document.getElementById('testForm');
   window.oldForm.style.display="none";
   document.getElementById('displayMessage').style.display="";
   document.getElementById('displayMessage').innerHTML = "thanks!";
}
```